# How to remove gcloud fully?

Tags: macos, gcloud

I'm new on mac. I just remove gcloud folders. And now when I open my command line window I always see next:
-bash: /Users/myuser/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc: No such file or directory

I know that made mistake removing not with gcloud command. But we have whad we have. So the main question is how to not get current logs when opening command line window on mac?

Comment: Look in your `.bashrc` for `source ~/gcloud/…` or `. ~/gcloud/…`, probably.

Answer (score 3):

The Cloud SDK makes *only* the following changes to the filesystem on installation:

1. Adds and populates the Cloud SDK root directory, where you directed the installer.
2. Configuration goes in the `~/.config/gcloud` directory (by default).
3. Modifies the RC files that you specified on installation (in response to the questions `Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable shell command
   completion? (Y/n)?` and `Enter a path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use [/Users/$USER/.bash_profile]:`.

These paths are slightly different on different platforms, but the three types of files (installation files, per-user config, and .rc files) are the same.