# I deleted a file called 'exec -l' from my home folder and now kubectl gives me an error

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl

In my home folder (on macOS) I noticed a strange file called 'exec -l'. I deleted it, and now when I try to use `kubectl` I get the following error:

```
localhost:~ alex$ kubectl --namespace sandbox get pods
Unable to connect to the server: 
error executing access token command "/Users/alex/exec -l 
/bin/bash/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json":
err=fork/exec /Users/alex/exec -l /bin/bash/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: 
no such file or directory output= stderr=
```

Is there any way I can get that file back? What even was it?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#operations

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the comment! However, I'm not looking for what the `exec` command does in `kubectl`. Rather, I'm trying to understand what the file on my system that was called `exec -l` did and how I can replace it. Unless that documentation does cover that, in which case pardon my ignorance!

Comment: Might be the way you are authenticating against the cluster. How did you initially authenticate ? Maybe try that again ?

Comment: Looking at `kubectl config view`, I see that I have `cmd-path: /Users/alex/exec -l /bin/bash/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` which is clearly the source of the problem. However I have no idea what this is or how to change it (or what to change it to)!

Comment: Turns out that config is in `~/.kube/config` for me at least. I changed it to gcloud's binary, still fails.

Comment: Still not sure what happened - I had uninstalled before and reinstalled to no avail - turns out I wasn't deleting some stuff in my .bashrc that gcloud had left behind. Following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854167/how-to-remove-gcloud-fully?rq=1 and then installing from scratch did the trick